# ASM- using a procedure to find if array a exist in array b on the same order

Tags: assembly, x86

First of all,i wanted to say that for 5 hours i tried to find an answer.

An Array A and Array B were set. a procedure named TEST1 will get an value V and return if the value exsist in array B or not. 
If it does-store the index in P, if not, store -1 in P.(I found an answer for this but for the following section you must use it)
Now the hard problem:On the following secion they wanted me to use this procedure-TEST1 to find if array a exists in array b on the same order.

(array a will be found in array b consecutively)

My idea for the last section was:

We will define 3 variables in size of DB:   Flag (0),Count(0),Check(0).
We will pass the value in array a to variable V.
Each time we will "call" the procedure and check if variable P is different from -1
if it does, variable Flag will increase in 1.

The program will check if Flag is equal to 1,
if it does,flag will decrease in 1 and count will increase in 1.
On the first time that flag will be equal to 0 after calling the procedure,Count will be kept in variable Check.
Each time before  variable Count becomes equal to 0,the program will compare variable Check and  variable Count.
variable Check will have to highest value of variable Count and then variable Count will be reset.All of this will be in a loop that will run about 100 times.
If variable Check will be equal to 10, array A exists in array B on the same order.

Remember:array B's Length is always higher then arrays A's Length so no need to check which has higher length.

The program should begin with the following datas:

```
ARR_B DB 100 DUP() 

ARR_A DB 10 DUP () 

V DB ? 

P DB ?
```

No matter how hard i tried to implement this idea, it still did not work(when i try to run it, it gives an error message of invalid index and lack of memory-when I try to fix the error the program allowed to enter the numbers but it get stuck before it gives the massage if array a exists in array b).

Please use basic commands like jump,cmp,interrupts and not advanced commands that will be not hard to understand.is there a better solution for this problem? what?

My solution:(that still not work)

```
Data Segment 
    ARR_B DB 100 DUP(?) 
    ARR_A DB 10 DUP(?) 
    V DB ? P DB ? 
    FLAG DB (0) 
    Message1 DB 'Array A found in array B','$' 
    Message2 DB 'Array A is not found in array B','$' 
DATA ends

Code Segment Assume CS:CODE,DS:DATA

IntakeB PROC 
    MOV AH,1H 
    INT 21H 
    MOV ARR_B[SI],AL 
    INC SI 
    RET 
endp

IntakeA PROC 
    MOV AH,1H 
    INT 21H 
    MOV ARR_A[SI],AL 
    INC SI 
    RET 
endp

TEST1 PROC 
    MOV AH,1 
    NEG AH 
    MOV P,AH 

SEARCH: 
    MOV DL,ARR_B[BX] 
    CMP V,DL 
    JE EQUAL 
    INC BX 
    LOOP SEARCH 
    JMP RETURN 

EQUAL: 
    MOV P,BL 

RETURN: 
    RET
endp

FIND PROC
SEARCH2: 
    CMP V,ARR_B[BX] 
    JE EQUAL2 
    RET 
    MOV FLAG,0 

EQUAL2: 
    INC BX 
    INC FLAG 
    LOOP SEARCH2 
endp

START: 
    MOV AX,DATA 
    MOV DS,AX 
    MOV SI,0H 
    MOV CX,100 

ValuesB: 
    CALL IntakeB 
    LOOP ValuesB 
    MOV SI,0H 
    MOV CX,10 

ValuesA: 
    CALL IntakeA 
    LOOP ValuesA 
    MOV BX,0H 
    MOV CX,100 
    MOV SI,0H 

CHECK: 
    MOV V,ARR_A[SI] 
    CALL TEST1 
    MOV CH,-1 
    CMP P,CH 
    JNE FIRST 
    JMP FINISH

FIRST: 
    MOV AH,0 
    MOV CX,10 
    MOV BX,0H 
    MOV AL,P 
    MOV V,ARR_B[AX] 
    CALL FIND
    MOV AH,0
    CMP FLAG,AH
    JE EQUAL5
    MOV BL,0H
    MOV AH,9H
    MOV DX,OFFSET Message2
    INT 21H
    JMP FINISH

EQUAL5: 
    MOV BL,1H 
    MOV AH,9H 
    MOV DX,OFFSET Message1 
    INT 21H 

FINISH: 
    MOV AX,4C00H 
    INT 21H

END START
CODE ENDS
```

Comment: but how it could help, it only check one value and remember all values of array a should be exists in array b on the same order,in this solution you have offered variable count will be incorrect.maybe it will help: Example of Correct arrays that one is found in the other: A:3,-5,0,8,5,11       B: 15,3,4,3,-5,0,8,5,11,2

Comment: example of arrays that are not A:0,2,4    B:0,1,2,3,4,5,6                my teacher didnt like the command of "repnz scasb". so please try to use base commands.

Comment: Where's the code? `ARR_B DB 100 DUP()` `ARR_A DB 10 DUP ()` `V DB ?` `P DB ?` isn't much of an attempt in implementation. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I wasent asking for the code,i was searching for a better idea, that will also work,if you would read all the post you would understand that.

Comment: An advice: please make your label names more expressive than `Z` and `E` and your variable names more expressive than `V` and `P`. IMHO it's really hard to read code when variable and label names mean nothing. It doesn't matter that much if the labels are in a language I don't understand at all, as long as eg. translate.google.com can translate it.

Comment: I understand that my solution is not good. i did the question 3 times and got the same answer that is difficult to understand.The content of the question is problematic,with the base commands of half year experience you cannot expect for something better. I am a beginner that ask questions,with more experience my answers will be better but at that moment i am asking for help using base commands and thats what makes it hard.I failed to get better solutions with the commands i mentioned.

Comment: I've read this question multiple times and still am not sure exactly what you're trying to do. If you have a hard time designing the algorithm in assembly from scratch, then don't. Do a prototype in a high-level language that you're familiar with instead (C, Java, Basic or whatever you prefer). Once you have it working you can start translating that code into assembly, i.e. breaking down complex expressions into simpler ones and selecting appropriate instructions.

Comment: i hope that the new solution will be fine for you.